# Proving that $n$ is not a prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, legendre-symbol, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $n=3^{100}+2$ and assume that $X^2-53$ does not have zeroes in $\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}$. Show that $n$ is not a prime.

I tried solving this problem by assuming that $n$ is a prime (in order to reach a contradiction). Then, using the law of quadratic reciprocity for Legendre symbols, we get $-1=\left(\frac{53}{3^{100}+2}\right)=\left(\frac{3^{100}+2}{53}\right)$. However, I do not know how to proceed from here.

Comment: What happens if you continue to compute the Legendre symbol using quadratic reciprocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Start with Fermat's little theorem:
$$3^{100} = 3^{52}\cdot 3^{52}\cdot 3^{-4} \equiv 3^{-4}\mod{53}.$$
Now all you have to do is find the inverse of $3$ modulo $53$ (or just note that $3^{-4}$ is clearly a square) and continue with what you've been doing to compute the Jacobi symbol.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have now been able to solve it.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?